# React Native, How to give grandchild a custom style?

Tags: react-native, function

So I have a component that I want to reuse, but sometimes I want to make minor differences with the grandchildren.

So Grandchild A could have a green border, while Grandchild B could have a blue one.

Here is a simplification of my code:

```
function Parent() {

  const contentA = {
    text: "Hello",
    number: 10 
  }

  const contentB = {
    text: "Again",
    number: 15
  }

  return (
    <Child content={contentA} />
    <Child content={contentB} />
  )
}

-----------------------------------------------------------

function Child({ content }) {

  return (
    <View style={{ padding: 10, margin: 10, backgroundColor: "gray" }}>
      <Grandchild content={content} />
    </View>
  )
}

-----------------------------------------------------------

function Grandchild({ content }) {

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{content.text}</Text>
      <Text>{content.number}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I was thinking if there was anyway that I could pass the style like this.

```
function Parent() {

  return (
    <Child extraStyle={"{borderColor: "Green"}"} />
    <Child extraStyle={"{borderColor: "Blue"}"} />
  )
}

-----------------------------------------------------------

function Child({ extraStyle }) {

  return (
    <Grandchild extraStyle={extraStyle} />
  )
}

-----------------------------------------------------------

function Grandchild({ extraStyle }) {

  return (
    <View style={extraStyle} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Remove the extra quotes and it should work `<Child extraStyle={{ borderColor: "Green" }} />`

Comment: That worked! Thank you :) 
@HardikChavda

Answer (score 0):

@HardikChavda gave me the answer:

"Remove the extra quotes and it should work `<Child extraStyle={{ borderColor: "Green" }} />`"